# How to script in hubot?

Tags: javascript, hubot, rocket.chat

The question is: I joined in a website and got a script to use as bot. I'm using hubot by the way.

The code is:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "__xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

var raw = JSON.stringify({"language":"pt_br","text":"sim"});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://yyyyyy/v2/parse/", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

When I start the bot, I get this error:

```
*Headers is not defined
at Object. (/home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/scripts/leadtest.js:1:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (/home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/register.js:53:36)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
at Robot.loadFile (/home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.js:360:22)
at /home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.js:383:52
at Array.map (:null:null)
at Robot.load (/home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.js:383:35)
at RocketChatBotAdapter.loadScripts (/home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot.js:115:9)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
at RocketChatBotAdapter.emit (events.js:315:20)
at /home/ubuntu/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate/node_modules/hubot-rocketchat/index.js:80:14
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)*
```

I got the problem is in the first line of the code, what is header and what should I do? What I'm missing? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You created a Header object in the first line of code as:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
```

Since the program is unable to find the Headers() object in the program, it is not able to initialize it. Thus giving the `Headers not defined` error.

Moving on to the next question: *What is headers?*:

The Headers interface of the Fetch API allows you to perform various actions on HTTP request and response headers. You can refer [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) to read more about it.

Finally, this issue is already addressed [here](https://github.com/swiftype/swiftype-app-search-javascript/issues/56), kindly refer it. However, if you want your answer here, then the workaround suggested is:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
global.fetch = fetch
global.Headers = fetch.Headers;
```

This is done because `Headers()` is a native construct to Fetch API and you will probably need to polyfill the Fetch API.

Comment: var myHeaders = new Headers(); cannot be empty? :o I didn't know because I got this code on a bot website. I don't know what to do now because in JS I'm absolutely noob!

Comment: This is another question, I recommend you to search for the question or post it as a separate question over SO. This helps finding and organizing questions over Stack Overflow easier and helps future users to use this website smoothly.

Comment: However, for the sake of your question, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/Headers) will explain you further over the arguments missing that gives you the error. Hope it helps :)